# Module not displaying in Prestashop 1.7.7.3

Tags: php, prestashop, hook, prestashop-1.7

I implemented a module in Prestashop to add a field in Orders page. Once filled, this field will appear in the bill of the purchase. My module worked well until 1.7.7.3 came... Now there is no display.

For now I replaced my module code with some sample code just to test the display but it doesn't work neither..
Could someone explain if there is an obvious error or advice a tutorial ?

```
<?php
if (!defined('_PS_VERSION_'))
  exit;

use PrestaShop\PrestaShop\Core\Payment\PaymentOption;
  
class PurchaseOrder extends PaymentModule
{
    public function install()
    {

        if ( parent::install()
            && $this->registerHook('displayAdminOrder')
            && $this->registerHook('displayAdminOrderLeft')
            && $this->registerHook('displayAdminOrderRight')
            && $this->registerHook('dsplayAdminOrderTabOrder')
            && $this->registerHook('displayAdminOrderContentShip')
            && $this->registerHook('displayAdminOrderContentOrder')
                       

        ) {
            return true;
        }

        $this->uninstall();
        return false;
    }

    /**
     * displayAdminOrderContentShip
     */
    public function hookDisplayAdminOrderContentShip($param)
    {
        return '<b>hookDisplayAdminOrderContentShip</b>';
    }

    /**
     * @hook displayAdminOrderLeft
     */
    public function hookDisplayAdminOrderLeft($param)
    {
        return '<b>hookDisplayAdminOrderLeft</b>';
    }

    /**
     * displayAdminOrderRight
     */
    public function hookDisplayAdminOrderRight($param)
    {
        return '<b>hookDisplayAdminOrderRight</b>';
    }

    /**
     * @hook displayAdminOrder
     */
    public function hookDisplayAdminOrder($param)
    {
        return '<b>hookDisplayAdminOrder</b>';
    }

    /**
     * displayAdminOrderContentOrder
     */
    public function hookDisplayAdminOrderContentOrder($param)
    {
        return '<b>hookDisplayAdminOrderContentOrder</b>';
    }
```

The display :

[Orders page display](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8Ej0M.png)

Comment: I faced a similar issue. Try to rename the functions with a lower letter hookdisplay....

Comment: Hi thanks for your response but it didn't work out for me... same problem.

Comment: Can you add some more details? From what i see your module is displaying  "hookDisplayAdminOrder". Correct? What else do you need? What you expect to see?

Comment: Ok so I'm trying to display hookDisplayAdminOrder in different areas. Problem is that it displays it only once at the bottom and all the hookDisplayAdminOrderLeft, right... are not display. What I expect is a grid of display of hookDisplayAdminOrder. Something broke when passing to the new version 1.7.7.3.

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 3):

Accordin to the [documentation](https://devdocs.prestashop.com/1.7/modules/core-updates/1.7.7/#modified-hooks) the hooks you are trying to use are no more available.

For instance:

- displayAdminOrderRight -> displayAdminOrderSideBottom
- displayAdminOrderLeft-> displayAdminOrderMainBottom

To solve it, uninstall your module, change the method's names and register the correct hooks.

Tips: if your module should be always compatible, then put both the hook (old and new) and call a separate method in that functions so you can achieve all the PS versions.

Comment: Thanks again. 
I made the change, uninstalled the module and then put it back again but there is no display now... not even the previous display.
I think something big missing in my config, what should I verify to see if my hooks are correct because for now nothing is displayed. I'm beginning with PS.